# How should I run an rle algorithm on a struct array?

Tags: c#, struct, run-length-encoding

I have a bunch of arrays of structs. Each struct contains 3 bytes and an sbyte.

For easier understanding here's a small code.

```
public class Container
{
    public A[] structs;
}

public struct A
{
    public byte a;
    public byte b;
    public byte c;
    public sbyte d;

    public A(byte a, byte b, sbyte d)
    {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = b;
       this.d = d;
    }
}
```

Now I have tons of these structs, therefore I would like to use RLE in order to compress it and use less memory.

On starting the program, a method procedurally generates values for the variables, then performs calculations on them. After that, the arrays are rarely used, but it's still necessary to "keep them alive".

I tried to convert the structs to uints using binary concatenation, but it wasn't the best solution. I've been thinking of converting the values to strings, but I think it would be very imperformant.

There's no way using bytes instead of sbytes.

What do you think would be the best solution to compress the arrays using RLE?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So just to confirm, you have a lot of values of this type, like in an array or similar collection, and a lot of them have the same value?

Comment: Exactly. Actually 80% of the values are the same, this was the reason I wanted to convert the structs to uints as it could have been compressed more efficiently.

Comment: But uints were not able to handle the sbytes.

Comment: When you say 80% of the values, is it going to be like bytes 1-4 are the same, 5th byte is different, 6-9 are the same as bytes 1-4, 10th is different? How are those 80/20% distributed? What is the pattern here?

Comment: Let me correct myself. In the array, 80% of the structs are the same.

Comment: Output it as a byte array, but make sure your RLE system simply evaluates and stores data per full block of 4 bytes to get one `A` struct. For the rest, I'd use [classic code-based RLE](http://www.shikadi.net/moddingwiki/RLE_Compression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's no way using bytes instead of sbytes.

Why? You can cast `sbyte` to `byte` and backward.

Save you data like `uint` and generate structs when they need

```
public struct A
{
    public byte a;
    public byte b;
    public byte c;
    public sbyte d;

    public A(uint value)
    {
       this.a = (byte)(value >> 24);
       this.b = (byte)(value >> 16);
       this.c = (byte)(value >> 8);
       this.d = (sbyte)value;
    }

    public uint Value => (uint)this.a << 24 | (uint)this.b << 16 | (uint)this.c << 8 | (uint)this.d;
}
```